# React useState hook not working as I would expect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the `useState` hook in React and it's behaving in an odd way.

If you look at the example below here is what I would expect: call `login`, on success it calls `setRefreshToken(responseToken)` then calls `refresh()` which references `refreshToken` set from `setRefreshToken`. What actually happens is `refreshToken` is undefined inside of `refresh()`.

I know `setState` is async but I haven't run in to issues like this before. Am I missing something?

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

const localStorageKey = "ar_refresh_token";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ tokenUrl, registerUrl, refreshUrl, children }) {
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(
    window.localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey)
  );

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();

  const login = async (userId, password) => {
    const response = await fetch(tokenUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userId,
        password
      })
    });


    if (response.status === 201) {
      const token = await response.text();
      setRefreshToken(token);
      window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, token);

      await refresh();
    }
  };

  const refresh = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(refreshUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `JWT ${refreshToken}`
      }
    });


    if (response.status === 201) {
      const token = await response.text();
      setAccessToken(token);
    }
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        refreshToken,
        accessToken,
        login,
        refresh
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Full example: https://github.com/analyticsrequired/auth-admin/blob/master/src/AuthContext.js

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that the component will not have been re-rendered before you call `refresh`, so the `refreshToken` inside `refresh` will be the default one.

You could instead pass in the `token` from `login` as an argument to `refresh` and use that and it will work as expected.

```
const login = async (userId, password) => {
  // ...
  if (response.status === 201) {
    // ...
    await refresh(token);
  }
};

const refresh = async refreshToken => {
  const response = await fetch(refreshUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `JWT ${refreshToken}`
    }
  });

  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to automatically call `refresh` whenever `refreshToken` changes:

```
...
    if (response.status === 201) {
      const token = await response.text();
      setRefreshToken(token);
      window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageKey, token);

      //await refresh();
    }
...
useEffect(
  () => {
    // your refresh code
  },
  [refreshToken]
)
```

The code inside `useEffect` will be called on the first render and after `refreshToken` is changed. So you don't need to call `refresh` after every call to `setRefreshToken`.